# Where can I put this $32^{\circ}$ F in the calculation, which is affecting my termperature drop?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that you turn off the heat in your home at night 2 hrs before you go to bed say at $t = 0$. If the temperature T at $t = 0$ is $66^{\circ}$ F and at that time you go to bed $(t=2)$ has dropped to $63^{\circ}$ F, what temperature can you expect in the morning, 8 hrs later $(t = 10)$? Of course, this process of cooling will depend on the outside temperature $T_A$ , which is assumed to be constant at $32^{\circ}$ F.                                                                                                                                     solution: $\log(T)=-kt+c$ when t=0, $T=66^{\circ}$ F so we get $c=\log 66$ and at $t=2, T=63$ we get the value of $k=-\frac12 \cdot\log(63/66)$. Now we get the values of both $k$ and $c$, we could substitute them in $\log(T)=-\frac12\cdot\log(63/66)t+\log(66)$. Now we can easily find the temperature $T$ at $t=10$.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $T=66e^{-kt}$. That is wrong. The assumption is surely that the rate of change depends on the temperature difference. So in 2 hours the difference drops from 34 to 31. You expect that over the next 8 hours the difference will drop again by a factor $(31/34)^4$ giving a final difference of $21.4^\circ$ or a temp of $44.6F$.

Comment: Hint: Think about what happens when time approaches infinity. What does the temperature approach?

Comment: So is it like $Log(T-32)=log(34)-log((31/34)^4)$

Comment: Why do you want to complicate things by using logs?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to model the temperature $T(t)$ in $^oF$ at time $t$ hours as decaying exponentially towards $T=32$, this suggests an equation of the form

$T(t)-32 = Ae^{-kt}$

where $A$ and $k$ are constants. Since you have $T(0)=66$, this tells you that $A=34$.

You also want $T(2)=63$, so you have

$63-32=34e^{-2k} \\ \Rightarrow e^{-2k} = \frac{31}{34}$

You could use logs to solve for $k$, but if you simply want to find the temperature at $T=10$ there is a shortcut. You have

$T(10) = 32 + 34e^{-10k} = 32 + 34\left(e^{-2k}\right)^5$

and you know the value of $e^{-2k}$ ...